# What do I need to do to earn the tier 6 mission chest reward?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

I've noticed that no matter how well my team and I have done in missions so far, we have never gotten a tier 6 mission chest. Even after earning two of three platinum medals, completing all optional objectives, and fully exploring the map, we barely scraped our way into the tier 5 chest (based on the progress bar displayed at the end of the mission).

Do certain conditions need to be attained, such as earning all *three* platinum medals *and* completing all optional objectives? Are there other "hidden" medals like the Explorer medal, which don't show up until you earn them that would improve our overall score?

Comment: Would love to know this too. It's annoying. But again, I think it's another thing that falls under - "They're working to fix it, it's not a perfect system yet".

Comment: If it means anything, I just got a level 6 chest for the first time. The Astro van mission and all platinum medals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about Total-Score. The earlier the mission (or the earlier in Story-Mode), the harder it is to get a higher Total-Score. So even if you max (All Plat) Utility/Building/Combat + All Bonuses + All Mission Side-Quests (Drone Landing, Storm Chest, ect..) The Total-Score still won't reach the minimum required to pop a Level 5/6 chest. The lower missions simply don't have enough potential score methods. A level 28 Mission can yield a level 5 chest pretty easy if you complete a few side quests, or a Drone Landing (Those things give a LOT of Exp). If you and a well organized team push through a 28 Mission you can get a level 6 chest. If you and a half-organized team jump into a level 40+ mission, level 6 chests are not to bad to snag. Though, will that that said, level 6 Chests just give a bit more of what you're already getting in a level 5/4/3 chest. So if the time it takes you to run ONE mission for a level 6 chest is longer then it would have taken to get two level 4 chests, it's kind of a waste (unless it's a Time-Reward for something you want, then it's worth the extra effort.

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't realize it'd be related to mission difficulty too. There's a lot of stuff that can't occur or be answered until later in the game but there's not an overwhelming amount of people there yet.

Comment: @n_palum and that makes me hopeful for long term playability, but it is tough making decisions early in the game with so much unknown about late game

Comment: This makes it sound like it's impossible to receive a tier 6 reward before a certain point in the game due to it being impossible to get a high enough score. Do you know what point that is or what score is required? I assume the score varies because I've gotten 22k on a mission and gotten a tier 3 chest, but scored 19k on a different mission and received a tier 4 chest.

Comment: @Vemonus It's not just score I presume because some missions just give out more than others. (I don't know exactly what is what but as an example) Say Ride the Lightning's gold medal for completion gives 2 tiers worth, Save the Survivors may give 3 tiers for base completion. I haven't been able to figure out the logic behind what medals give and why.

Answer (score -2):

One thing I do is build a really tall structure and just waste half of each stack of mats and then destroy the bottom piece so you get a 2 for 1 deal kinda thing